# Adding a new Node after specific node in Linked List Implementation

Tags: c#, linked-list

I am following some tutorial go implementing linkedlist in C#. This is my code which i copied from that tutorial.

```
 internal class Node
    {
        internal int data;
        internal Node next;
        public Node(int d)
        {
            data = d;
            next = null;
        }
    }
    internal class SingleLinkedList
    {
        public void printAllNodes()
        {
            Node current = head;
            while (current != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(current.data);
                current = current.next;
            }
        }
        internal Node head;
        internal void InsertFront(SingleLinkedList singlyList, int new_data)
        {
            Node new_node = new Node(new_data);
            new_node.next = singlyList.head;
            singlyList.head = new_node;
        }
        internal void InsertLast(SingleLinkedList singlyList, int new_data)
        {
            Node new_node = new Node(new_data);
            if (singlyList.head == null)
            {
                singlyList.head = new_node;
                return;
            }
            Node lastNode = GetLastNode(singlyList);
            lastNode.next = new_node;
        }
        internal Node GetLastNode(SingleLinkedList singlyList)
        {
            Node temp = singlyList.head;
            while (temp.next != null)
            {
                temp = temp.next;
            }
            return temp;
        }
        internal void InsertAfter(Node prev_node, int new_data)
        {
            if (prev_node == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The given previous node Cannot be null");
                return;
            }
            Node new_node = new Node(new_data);
            new_node.next = prev_node.next;
            prev_node.next = new_node;
        }
    }
}
```

Now i Added some nodes and displaying it which is working very fine.

```
SingleLinkedList obj = new SingleLinkedList();
            obj.InsertFront(obj, 7);
            obj.printAllNodes();
            obj.InsertFront(obj, 9);
            obj.printAllNodes();
            obj.InsertLast(obj, 345);
            obj.printAllNodes();
```

Now i want to use that "InsertAfter" function which i am using but it is not working correctly , it is still showing the old nodes.What's wrong with it?

```
obj.InsertAfter(new Node(7), 10);
            obj.printAllNodes();
```

Comment: You're creating new Node for the prev_node, which doesn't exist in your linked list. Then you try to add a next node to it. This is the reason you fail. Instead of `new Node(7)` in calling InsertAfter, use an existing node

Comment: I would love if you write it .

Comment: Little suggestion: Your GetLastNode, InsertLast and InsertFront (member) Methodes dont need the SingleLinkedList parameter. Use the keyword 'this' instead or make the methods static.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is your requirement:

```
SingleLinkedList obj = new SingleLinkedList();
obj.InsertFront(obj, 7);
obj.InsertFront(obj, 9);
var d = obj.GetLastNode(obj);
obj.InsertLast(obj, 345);
obj.InsertAfter(d, 44);
obj.printAllNodes();
```

I think this is the best solution if you don't change the class `SingleLinkedList`. But if I were you, I would consider editing that class.

**EDIT:**

I would implement "insert" methods like this:

```
internal Node InsertFront(SingleLinkedList singlyList, int new_data)
{
    Node new_node = new Node(new_data);
    new_node.next = singlyList.head;
    singlyList.head = new_node;
    return new_node;
}
```

So that instead of calling `obj.InsertFront(obj, 7);` I would call `Node node = obj.InsertFront(obj, 7);` and it would then help me to insert node after any node: `obj.InsertAfter(node, 44);`

Comment: so it means i have to create a new function in a class to find the node first.

Comment: Yes. Your  prev_node parameter must be a Node already in your SingleLinkedList.

Comment: I would recommend returning the created node in your InsertFront, InsertLast and other methods, where a node is being created. Then you won't need to create another method